# Query Transform postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I get an error with query

```
UPDATE schema1.table1 t
SET (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) = (
SELECT DISTINCT tt.a1, tt.a2, tt.a3, tt.a4, tt.a5
FROM schema1.table2 tt
WHERE tt.is_flg = 1
      AND tt.some_cnt > 0
      AND (t.date1 BETWEEN tt.date1 AND tt.date2)
      AND tt.id = t.id
);
More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

How can I transform query to catch rows which give this error?

UPD: I transform it with `with` but I don't sure that result set is correct, because query with `update` use 251 rows and query with `with`  and without `distinct` use 465 rows (`with & distinct` 51 rows)

```
with h as (select * from schema1.table1)
select DISTINCT tt.a1, tt.a2, tt.a3, tt.a4, tt.a5
    FROM schema1.table2 tt INNER JOIN h ON tt.id = t.id
    WHERE tt.is_flg = 1
          AND tt.some_cnt > 0
          AND (t.date1 BETWEEN tt.date1 AND tt.date2)
```

Comment: And then do what with them?

Comment: Transform to SELECT .. to see rows which in subquery